# Vue.js and jQuery Draggable not working

Tags: jquery-ui, vue.js

I've the following code:

**JS**

```
new Vue({
    el: 'body',
  data: {
    image: 'http://wpmedia.news.nationalpost.com/2016/07/faroe-islands-sheep-view.jpg?quality=65&strip=all&w=620'
  },

  ready:function(){
    this.setDraggable();
  },

  methods:{
    setDraggable: function(){

      var x1 = $('.img').width();
      var x2 = $('.bb-image-drag').width();

      $( ".bb-image-drag" ).draggable({
        axis: "x",
        drag: function(event, ui) {
          if(ui.position.left >= 0)
          ui.position.left = 0;
          else if(ui.position.left <= x1 - x2)
          ui.position.left = x1 - x2;
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) { $('#bbOffset').val(ui.position.left); }
      });
    }
  }
})
```

**Markup**

```
<div class="img mob-nom-img" style="position: relative;">
  <div class="text-center">
  <span style="margin-top: 400px;left: 30%;" class="drag-label">&#8596;  Drag to adjust</span></div>
  <img :src="image" class="bb-image-drag">
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yn99de5n/3/

But, the draggable is not functioning properly. It's flickring and dragging to left 0 to max quickly.

I think it's mainly because the Vue is rendered after the draggable function call. But I couldn't find a method to solve this. Any idea?

Comment: I don't really understand what it is supposed to do... Could you detail the expected behavior ?

Comment: It's kind of obvious it is sticking to the left with your condition : `if (ui.position.left >= 0) { ui.position.left = 0; }`